# Use HttpWebRequest to Simulate Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control

I am automating a website with HttpWebRequests. The website in question requires Internet Explorer for the web application to work correctly.  Because I'm not using a webBrowser control, the web request just returns a page notifying me that I need to be using Internet Explorer.  Is there a way to trick the website into thinking that I'm using Internet Explorer, or will I have to use the webBrowser control?

Comment: +1 for going out of your way to refuse to use internet explorer

Comment: Well, I am trying to optimize the process.  Doing everything with HttpWebRequests and Responses is faster than doing everything with the WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `UserAgent` string:

```
public static void PretendToBeIE(HttpWebRequest request)
{
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 9.0; en-US)";
}
```

There is no guarantee that it will work though, everything depends on web app you are using.